# What is the point declaring variables at the end of class?

Tags: class-design

I saw multiple examples in MSDN that uses to declare the internal fields at the end of the class. What is the point?

I find this a little embarrassing, because each time Visual Studio adds a method it adds it to the end of the class, so there is need every time to move it...

```
class A
{
  public A(){}
  // Methods, Properties, etc ...

  private string name;
}

class A
{
  private string name;

  public A(){}  
  // Methods, Properties, etc ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, it makes sense to put the public interface of the class at the top, so that any *user* of the class can open up your header file and quickly see what's available. By implication, protected and private members are put at the bottom.

In C# and Java, where interface and implementation are completely intertwined, people would probably not open your class's source code to see what's available. Instead they would rely on code completion or generated documentation. In that case, the ordering of the class members is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

If it's obvious the variable has been declared, and the code is by way of an example, then arguably this gets you to the bit being demonstrated quicker - that's all I can think of.

Add-ins like ReSharper will allow you to standardise and automatically apply this layout at the touch of a key combination, by the way, if it is what you want.

Comment: so, you think in MSDN it was used for demonstration purpose only, without any "hidden crafty" logic bellow.

Answer (score 1):

Many programmers strive for self-documenting code that helps clients to understand it. In C++ class declaration, they would go from most important (i.e. what is probably most frequently inspected) to least important:

```
class Class {
public:
    // First what interest all clients.

    static Class FromFoobar(float foobar); // Named constructors in client code
                                           // often document best

    Class();                               // "Unnamed" constructors.

    /* public methods */

protected:

    // This is only of interest to those who specialize
    // your class.

private:
    // Of interest to your class.
};
```

Building on that, if you use Qt, the following ordering might be interesting:

```
class SomeQtClass : public QObject {
public:
signals:       // what clients can couple on
public slots:  // what clients can couple to

protected:
protected slots:
};
```

Then the same down for protected and private slots. There is no specific reason why I prefer signals over slots; maybe because signals are always public, but I guess the ordering of them would depend on the situation, anyhow, I keep it consistent.

Another bit I like is to use the access-specifiers to visually seperate behaviour from data (following the importance ordering, behaviour first, data last, because behaviour is the top-interest for the class implementor):

```
class Class {
private:
    void foobar() ;

private:
    float frob_;
    int   glob_;
};
```

Keeping the last rule helps to prevent visual scattering of class components (we all know how some legacy classes look like over time, when variables and functions are mixed up, not?).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any valid reason for this. If you run Code Analysis on a class declared like this you'll get an error as private fields should be declared on top of classes (and below constants).